# What is the 'authority' to be used to generate URI for an external file directory on Android?

Tags: java, android

Particularly, I want to use it with the method:
`FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,authority, file);`

I am creating the file under:
`Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` 
Use of:
`"com.example.android.fileprovider"`,
`"com.example.android.provider"`
`"com.example.<MyAppName>.fileprovider"`
`"com.example.<MyAppName>.provider"`
`"${applicationId}.provider"`
`"${applicationId}.fileprovider"`

as authority have resulted in return of Null reference for URI

My Compile SDK Version: 28
Build Tools version 27.0.3

Comment: The same authority as used in manifest file in your provider definition.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps. Initially I didn't have a file provider section at all in the manifest assuming it is not required for an 'external file'. 
Q1: But then, how to find what should be the authority to mention in Manifest file provider def (and therefore in code), though I used com.example.<myappname>.fileprovider and it worked.

But in addition, I also needed to give the actual external file path in resource xml which on my device happens to be: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myfirstapp/files/Pictures (that I found in debug mode).
This fixed the problem of null URI return.

Comment: Qs: 2. Does the external file path depend on Android/APK version?
      3. Is there a way to find or mention it in XML without hard-coding the path?

Comment: Post the provider definition. Post your xml file. And not in comments!